# I want to exceute one process only after completion of another process in my django application using celery

Tags: django, celery, celery-task

I am new to the celery thing.
I want to run one process only after the completion of another one.
While searching I found one code

```
class CallbackTask(Task):
    def on_success(self, retval, task_id, args, kwargs):
        print("success")
        pass

    def on_failure(self, exc, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo):
        print("fail")
        pass


@celery.task(base=CallbackTask) # this does the trick
def add_val(x, y):
    time.sleep(20)
    return x + y
```

while running that code, it shows status in the following order:

1. Received task

   //After 20 min timer
2. success(it is getting printed from 'on_success' method)

3.task completed (#ans-7)

Actually, the problem here is 'success' is getting printed before my actual answer, if there is any way that I get that after my answer, then I can easily put my second process in the 'on_success' method and execute it.

Answer (score 0):

The task is already completed because the `on_success` gets the return value. Its just the way when celery logs things it looks like the `on_success` was runned before the return of the function `add_val`

Comment: thanks for your reply, but in this case, if I execute any other process then that will be executed before the first one is completed, so is there any other way to do that?

Comment: If you start an other process in `on_success` that task is completed (https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.on_success). And you could even send the result of that task to your new process, the result of your task would be in `retval`.

Answer (score 0):

Although the `on_success` approach might work, I believe that either [callbacks](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#callbacks) or [chains](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chains) would be the "official" way to handle this.